# disable tls1.0 1.1 apache

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4

On my server with ubuntu 18.04.4 and apache 2.4.41
Im trying to disable tls1.0 and 1.1 by editing:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf
```

with:

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

And afterwards running

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

However when I check my domain at https://www.ssllabs.com it still says

> This server supports TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1. Grade capped to B.

I was following this https://gist.github.com/GAS85/42a5469b32659a0aecc60fa2d4990308 manual.

Im trying to config my first https website by using certbot.

How can I disable tls1.0 and 1.1 on an ubuntu server running apache.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Ah the comment by Memes fixed it :) "if you are using Letsencrypt, do not forget to check /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf " It seems like the other file mentiond in the manual is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the line this:   -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

```
SSLProtocol -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

otherwise you only add TLS 1.2 and 1.3